# Is SQL Injection possible with mysql_real_escape_string when variables in the query have no quotes around them?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

Take for example this

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password";
```

If there are no quotes around $username and $password, is injection still possible ?

Comment: Does that even work? I mean, even with "valid" values for username and password, the query should fail, as strings **need** to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: @Shi it will work if you use valid SQL inside `username`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/632951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there are no quotes around $username and $password, is injection still possible ?

Yes. `mysql_real_escape_string()` prevents only escaping from the quotes in a string.

Without surrounding quotes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Trivially, submit the username as username and the password as password.  Congratulations, you're in.  That's because this expands to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = username AND password = password";
```

It will select any row where the `username` column equals the `username` column (same for password).

Of course, this code also fails for ordinary logins, so it should be caught pretty quickly.  If you use *any* username or password that is not a database construct (column, function call, etc.), it will fail.

Comment: @Pekka, sorry, I did not mean the form submission should contain quotes.  The `username` should actually be username (no quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Without the quotes, the user-submitted data will be seen as field references, and/or invalid SQL.

Consider a username of `username`.  A proper query would be:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE username='username'
```

and only match if there really is a user whose name is "username".

Without the quotes, it becomes:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE username=username
```

which would match ALL non-null records in the table.

Now consider a 2-part username: `John doe`

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE username=John doe
```

The DB server will try to compare the username field against a field name 'John', which most likely doesn't exist. Then there's this "doe" thing in there which is not a field name, not an SQL key word, so is a syntax error.

Now consider a username:  `1 or 1=1`

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE username=1 or 1=1
```

again, this will ALWAYS return true and match ALL rows, because "1=1" will always be true.

mysql_real_escape_string() only guarantees that any data you pass through it will not "break" a PROPERLY CONSTRUCTED query. If the query you're inserting the escaped data into is NOT properly constructed, then all bets are off.